# Sending rich text to email

Tags: c#, .net, system.net.mail

I faced a problem sending the text as html markup in a message to mail. At first, I convert rtf to html

```
string GetHtmlContent(string someRTFtext)
{
    RichEditDocumentServer server = new RichEditDocumentServer();
    server.RtfText = someRTFtext;
    server.Options.Export.Html.CssPropertiesExportType = DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.Export.Html.CssPropertiesExportType.Inline;
    server.Options.Export.Html.DefaultCharacterPropertiesExportToCss = true;
    server.Options.Export.Html.EmbedImages = true;
    server.Options.Export.Html.ExportRootTag = DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.Export.Html.ExportRootTag.Body;

    return server.HtmlText;
}
```

This method return me

```
<body>
<style type="text/css">
    .cs2E86D3A6{text-align:center;text-indent:0pt;margin:0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt}
    .cs88F66593{color:#800080;background-color:transparent;font-family:Arial;font-size:8pt;font-weight:bold;font-style:normal;}
</style>
<p class="cs2E86D3A6"><span class="cs88F66593">Форматированый текст</span></p></body>
```

but the post came simple text, without any selections, fonts, etc.
Here is a method of sending

```
try
{
    string login = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailLogin"];
    string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailPassword"];

    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.From = new MailAddress(login);

    if (lbStudents.Items.Count == 0)
        MessageBox.Show("Error.", "Sending massage", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    foreach (SmallStudent student in lbStudents.Items)
    {
        mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(student.Email));
    }

    if (txtSubject.Text.Trim() == String.Empty)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error.", "Sending massage",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        return;
    }

    mail.Subject = txtSubject.Text.Trim();
    mail.Body = GetHtmlContent(rtfEditor.DocumentRtf);
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    mail.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    client.Port = 587;
    client.EnableSsl = true;
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(login.Split('@')[0], password);
    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    client.Send(mail);
    mail.Dispose();
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Exception: " + exception.Message, 
                    "Sending massage", 
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                    MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

Comment: I am not sure the <style> markup is working on HTML body with `MailMessage`

Comment: Сan you suggest other ways to send e-mail formatted text with pictures?

Comment: Do what the @Douglas said, it is only way to do this.

Comment: Most email clients can display embedded images in HTML. Search around for ways how to do this (or find a library that automates it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several email clients, including Gmail webmail, do not support `<style>` elements; see [CSS Support Guide for Email Clients](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/).

You'll get better compatibility by inlining your styles through `style="..."` attributes:

```
<body>
<p style="text-align:center;text-indent:0pt;margin:0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt">
    <span style="color:#800080;background-color:transparent;font-family:Arial;font-size:8pt;font-weight:bold;font-style:normal;">Форматированый текст</span>
</p>
</body>
```

This may introduce a lot of repetition, so consider using an automated process for inlining the styles if you have many styled elements.

Comment: Thank you, I will think how to implement it.

Comment: Check this out.. its a lib to inline css https://github.com/milkshakesoftware/PreMailer.Net